# ERD for a Contract between a Writer and a Publisher: Is it correct, can it be simpler?

Tags: database-design, erd, database-diagrams

I created an entity-relationship diagram (ERD) for a *book publishing* business context that I will detail bellow.

### Entity types

The entity types of interest are:

- `Writer`
- `Work` (as a *book*)
- `Publisher`
- `Split` (some kind of *contract*, representing the *share* of the whole `Work` *ownership* between `Writers` and `Publishers`, totalling 100%)

### Business rules

1. A `Writer` can have multiple `Publishers`.

   - And a `Publisher` can have multiple `Writers`.
2. A `Work` can have one or many `Writers`.

   - And a `Writer` can have many `Works`.
3. `Works` can have one or many `Publishers`.

   - And a `Publisher` can have multiple `Works`.
4. For each `Writer` or `Publisher` on a `Work`, a `Split` must be be assigned.
5. A `Split` can have multiple `Versions` and each `SplitVersion` can have
   different `WriterPercents` and `PublisherPercentage`.

### Example

Let us suposse that *Splits Version No. 1* is as follows:

- *Writer 1* = 50%
- *Writer 2* = 50%
- *Publisher 1* = 50%
- *Publisher 2* = 50%

Then, one of the *Writers* modifies the *Splits* to *Version no. 2*:

- *Writer 1* = 55%
- *Writer 2* = 45%
- *Publisher 1* = 60%
- *Publisher 2* = 40%

### Entity-Relationship diagram

Here is the ERD I have built so far:

[image: Database mode]

You can download the [MySQL Workbench file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6JwmeMisBlHeDF3YXYxamFoeVE/view?usp=sharing) that corresponds to the current schema, if necessary.

**Note:** This was my first model but I think some elements might not be relevant now, as per the following @MDCCL comment:

> Can a specific `Writer` have a *contract* with a determined `Publisher` **even if** such *publisher* has issued **none** the `Works` of said *writer*?

And the answer is yes, did not thought of that. In this regard, should I introduce a new relationship into the diagram?

### Questions

So, I would like opinions on:

- Is my ERD representing the given rules correctly?
- Is there some simpler layout that could solve the discussed scenario?

Comment: 1.Doesn't the rule #4 say PublisherSplit must reference PublisherWork, and WriterSplit  must  reference  WriterWork? That is, no version  of split of work is possible whithout taking part in work?

Comment: I think it is too simplistic. What about multi book contracts? More complex payment distributions?

Comment: @Serg, correct, everyone in the split has part of the work.

Comment: @TomTom, no multi book contracts. One book = one contract.